# Columns to Row in SQL Server without union

Tags: sql-server

```
create table #temp 
(tempid int, 
 tempname nvarchar(50), 
 option1 nvarchar(50),
 option2 nvarchar(50),
 option3 nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #temp (tempid, tempname, option1, option2, option3) 
values (1, 'YesNoCancel', 'Yes', 'No', 'Cancel')
```

I want output as

```
         tempid tempname       options
          1    'YesNOCancel'   'yes'
          1    'YesNOCancel'   'no'
          1    'YesNOCancel'   'cancel'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
SELECT t.*
FROM temp
OUTER APPLY 
(
    VALUES 
        (tempid, tempname, option1),
        (tempid, tempname, option2),
        (tempid, tempname, option3)

) t(tempid, tempname, option1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would really help you:

```
 SELECT t.tempid,
      x.tempname,
      x.option1  
    FROM #temp t
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
        VALUES 
            (tempid, tempname, option1),
            (tempid, tempname, option2),
            (tempid, tempname, option3)
    ) x (tempid, tempname, option1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this

```
Select tempid,tempname,OptionVal
From #temp 
UNPIVOT (OptionVal FOR Options IN (option1, option2, option3) ) AS T
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/16712)**